# Filter out business days from dates column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with 2 columns Date and Sales. How to filter only business days from the dataframe. Tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
dataset <- subset(SalesData, SlaesData$BusinessDate >= "2016-02-05", SalesData$BusinessDate[isWeekday(SalesData$BusinessDate)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(chron)
#sample data
df <- data.frame(report_date=as.Date(c('2017-11-07','2017-11-05','2017-11-04')), sales=c(100,200,400))

#subset of sample data having only business days
df[!is.weekend(df$report_date),]
```